# Have Image in Header Span Full Width of page

Tags: ms-word

In word 2000 I inserted a .jpg into my header, but it shrinks the image down.  If I try to expand the image to fit the entire width of the page it only extends one side of the image (running it off the page).  What do I need to do so the image in the header runs from the left side of the page to the right side of the page?